# Unknown file system after copying Debian ISO with dd

Tags: filesystems, dd, iso

After copying the last version of Stretch distro on a 4GB USB drive with `sudo dd bs=4M if=debian-testing-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdb1 && sync` on a Lubuntu 16.04 system, the file system of `sdb1` shows as 'unknown'. This is the case after creating a ms-dos or gpt partition table, a single partition, and formatting it with ext4 or FAT32 file system, which shows correctly after formatting, but goes to unknown after the `dd` command completes. Actually, the drive does not boot the computer, it simply gets stuck (although this might be caused by other reasons). I've also tried, with the same result, after executing `isohybrid` on the ISO file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to overwrite the USB key including its partition table:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=debian-testing-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

(`sdb` instead of `sdb1`). The download contains its own partition table.

See the [official instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en), which suggest

```
sudo cp debian-testing-amd64-netinst.iso /dev/sdb
sync
```

instead.

As pointed out by [Mioriin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/201836/mioriin), you should [verify the downloaded image](https://www.debian.org/CD/verify) before copying it to your key, to make sure it was downloaded correctly and more importantly that it hasn’t been tampered with.

Comment: Then, in such a case, it's not neccesary to prepare the pen drive in any way, just plug it in and dd the ISO.

Comment: @nightcod3r exactly.

Answer (score -2):

This is likely a corrupted download. Get the checksum signatures from the download page you got the .iso from and validate your downloaded file.
(it should have the instructions you need to perform the check)

If it fails the check, you need to download the image again and check that.

Repeat until the file passes the check. Then you have an image file that works.

Comment: I missed the partition number in the question, but I'm leaving the answer up since it's a good idea to validate downloaded .iso images before using them.

Comment: I agree it’s a good idea to verify downloads, but it needs to be done [properly](https://www.debian.org/CD/verify) — using checksums obtained from the same place as the downloaded image isn’t sufficient.